# How to check whether a SQL query has executed successfully in a IF-ELSE Control Statement in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am storing department name in a variable `@department` which I will be fetching from a row now for that particular department name I want to find out whether a department id exists or not in `departments` table means whether the department name entered by the user is a valid department or not. How to do  this? How do I turn this query into a boolean expression?

```
create table dbo.departments
(
    department_id int primary key;
    department_name varchar(255);
)

if(select @finaldepartment_id = department_id 
   from dbo.departments 
   where department_name like @department)
   set @department_flag = 1;
else
   set @department_flag = 0;
```

Comment: It really depends on how you want to use the result.  If used in another query I would use a different approach.  If you are using it for in a program (SP or c#j I might use a stored procedure or function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be simplified to single query

```
SET @department_flag = CASE 
                         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                      FROM   dbo.departments 
                                      WHERE  department_name LIKE Concat('%',@department,'%')) THEN 1
                         ELSE 0 
                       END
```

Comment: Using case seems to be optimal approach but it throws OUTPUT: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'.

Comment: @SiddharthBhardwaj - yeah, there was a typo fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

To check if there is any department that matches your condition use `EXISTS`

```
IF EXISTS (
  select 1 
  from dbo.departments 
  where department_name like '%'+@department+'%'
  )
```

If you need to assign an id from departments into a variable, set the variable with the result and then check if it's not null.